# az copy failed on premium storage account

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

Tried to copy data from Linux VM to Azure premium storage account. But that failed to copy data. For standard storage account data copied successfully using same VM. Log file doesn't have enough error details.

```
./azcopy cp "/opt/file.txt" "https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/test/?SAS" --recursive=true

Error 
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx62 summary
Elapsed Time (Minutes): 0.0333
Total Number Of Transfers: 1
Number of Transfers Completed: 0
Number of Transfers Failed: 1
Number of Transfers Skipped: 0
TotalBytesTransferred: 0
Final Job Status: Failed
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the reasons it could fail is because premium storage account only supports `Page` blobs (unless it is a Premium Block Blob account) and from the looks of it you're trying to copy a file size of which is not a multiple of 512 bytes.